# Needing the helper change transaction history in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

My website  has this code

```
$time  = human_time_diff(strtotime($customer_order->modified_date), current_time( 'timestamp' ) - (7 * 60 * 60) ).' '.__( 'trước' );
```

to count transaction history in woocommer. It’s mean the time is counted and result is showed that “1 hour ago”, “1 month ago” … now i want to change this code, i want the time is showed that day/month/year, ex: “29/7/2017”.
can anybody help me?

Comment: just use `$customer_order->modified_date` and format it as you want

Comment: can you give and take me more specific, i did but it’s not ok

Comment: what `$customer_order->modified_date` return ?

Comment: $customer_order = new WC_Order($order->ID);
                        $time  = human_time_diff(strtotime($customer_order->modified_date), current_time( 'timestamp' ) - (7 * 60 * 60) ).' '.__( 'trước' );
                        $customer_id = get_post_meta($order->ID, "_customer_user", true);
                        $items = $customer_order->get_items();

Comment: try `$time= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($customer_order->modified_date));`

Comment: did it work?.........